# Comment with suggested modifications deleted

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

*Note: I'm not asking a moderator to undelete it, because it isn't significant enough to matter.  It's more a matter of me understanding what is going on for future reference.*

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62915593/120242
My comment was along the lines of "what OP actually wants is [this small modification] to your code".  I proposed two possible small changes.  I didn't post a separate answer, because I didn't feel as if the changes warranted/required posting a new answer.  And that was fine, and you can see that she actually used and edited in one of my suggestions verbatim.

But it seems that my comment was deleted?  Am I not supposed to suggest changes and should have just posted my own answer?  Or was there another reason the comment was deleted?

Mind you, I suggested two possible suggestions to match OP's intention.  So, my comment still had some additional value of its own, because it points out an alternate representation (you may not want to unpack into the constructor as parameters, but feed dictionary data directly).
I can't see the reason for deletion, so I don't really know what is going on.

I noticed something similar happen with other people's suggestions on my own answers, and am wondering if it is some kind of SO policy on comments that should be answers, or something similar?

*On a sidenote, is there a way to see comment deletion reasons?*

Comment: Was you comment posted before the comment `@user120242 Added it. – Ann Zen 29 mins ago`?. If yes then maybe somebody flagged it and a moderator accepted the flag, with both not realizing that not *all* your proposed changes were incorporated in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it was posted before that.  Is it generally a normal thing to do to delete comments after their suggestions are incorporated?  So I should be flagging those when I see them?  Obviously it doesn't really matter that much, I'd just like to know what the reason is for future reference.

Comment: Personally I think flagging all these comments is pointless, but there is a `It's no longer needed.` comment flag reason, and many believe that it applies in these cases.

Comment: @yivi does that include my second suggestion not using **kwargs and ** to unpack?   
 Or is it more likely that (as user000001 pointed out) flagger and mod just didn't notice?  It arguably has value because, for example, it could be suggested that the use of **kwargs there is unnecessary, since you are converting a parsed JSON structure to a class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728243/is-self-dict-updatekwargs-good-or-poor-style  Note again:  I'm just asking for reference

Comment: If you feel there was something missed in your deleted comment that still holds relevance, post another comment.